# Minor ticks not showing when using matlab2tikz

Tags: pgfplots, matlab

I am using `matlab2tikz` to import MATLAB figures into TeX.

However I can't seem to get the x or y minor ticks to show in the document compiled by TeX. The MATLAB figure I have converted to `.tikz` have the minor ticks on both axes. The plot in the figure is linear.

In the `.tikz` file the `xminorticks=true` and `yminorticks=true` options are present.

Why won't the minor ticks appear in the compiled document?

EDIT:
Code generated by `matlab2tikz` which reproduce the problem for me, all point are spaced evenly:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
view={0}{90},
width=14cm,
height=6cm,
scale only axis,
xmin=1, xmax=10,
xminorticks=true,
ymin=2, ymax=20,
yminorticks=true]
\addplot [
color=blue,
solid,
forget plot
]
coordinates{
 (1,2)(2,4)(3,6)(4,8)(5,10)(6,12)(7,14)(8,16)(9,18)(10,20) 
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code generated by `matlab2tikz`?

Comment: pgfplots will avoid minor ticks if the distance between adjacent ticks various from tick-to-tick. Might that be the case here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell PGFPlots how many minor ticks you want between each pair of major ticks, by setting `minor tick num=<value>`. You don't need to explicitly turn on the minor ticks with `xminorticks=true`, this happens automatically.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
view={0}{90},
width=14cm,
height=6cm,
scale only axis,
xmin=1, xmax=10,
ymin=2, ymax=20,
minor tick num=1]
\addplot [
color=blue,
solid,
forget plot
]
coordinates{
 (1,2)(2,4)(3,6)(4,8)(5,10)(6,12)(7,14)(8,16)(9,18)(10,20) 
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```