# Does pgfplots ignore the minor grid?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, formatting, grids

I'm trying to plot an easy function and I would like to enable the minor grid.
But it seems that this instruction is ignored. I used the `grid=both` option but it has no effect. The only grid I can see is the major grid. I could not find anything helpful on the internet. Thanks for any advise.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}                
\geometry{a6paper}                   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings} 
\title{Control}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[grid=both,xlabel={error},ylabel={power}]
\addplot[mark=none,domain=4:30,samples=200]{55/(1.3*(ln(x)/ln(10)))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Related -- http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/81815/34618.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To get a minor grid you need minor ticks. You can enable those with e.g. `minor tick num=2` which adds two minor ticks between each major tick.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[grid=both,xlabel={error},ylabel={power},minor tick num=2]
\addplot[mark=none,domain=4:30,samples=200]{55/(1.3*(ln(x)/ln(10)))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```