# Add unannotated marks to a pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

I'm plotting experimental data with `pgfplots` and wonder how I can add smaller ticks to the axis which are not annotated.
Every data analysis software (even Excel) makes this, but I didn't find a way to do it easily in `pgfplots`. I must have overlooked it.

[image: example]

I hope there is a way to tell `pgfplots` to split every "big" step (0-5, 5-10, ...) into, lets say, five smaller steps.

Comment: you can search the manual for minor ticks num

Comment: See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152198/does-pgfplots-ignore-the-minor-grid/152201#152201

Comment: Did the trick of percusse or Torbjørn respectively answer your question or do you need further assistance?